# /dev/serial directory no longer appearing in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, serial-port

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu install from 20.04 to 22.04. I use zwave with the install for home automation things. I'd gotten my zwave controller to work with it's software by finding it's id in /dev/serial/by-id. In 22.04 there is no /dev/serial folder at all. What am I missing?